# Heap Spray Internet Explorer 8

Tags: exploit

I want to know, is there a way to spray IE8 heap?

I did my best but I was not able to spray IE 8 heap! I attached Olly to IE and I never see my data in Memory of IE.

How can I do that? I also used Heaplib, but again no luck!

Any advice? Is it impossible to spray IE 8 heap?

Thanks

Comment: Could you say what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

IE7 & 8 run in isolated processes explicitly to prevent this type of attack. For hacking research you'll need to turn to sites that focus on that type of study. You won't find much support here.